# I need help with a transitive closure question

Tags: relations

the question deals with relations

$R$ is a binary relation defined on $A = \{0,1,2,3\}$.

Let $R = \{(0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,0)\}$.

Find $R^t$, the transitive closure of $R$.

I have the answer but I can't seem to figure out how to get to the answer.
The answer: $\{(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)\}$

I dont understand the order of the points. For example, why is it (1,2) instead of (2,1)?

If anyone knows the steps or a website that can help with transitive closures, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I like [this definition](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Transitive_Closure_(Relation_Theory)/Finite_Chain) for such calculations.

Comment: But there are other good ways that may be more efficient for finite cases. For example, you can iteratively expand the relation by adding in all two-link chains until there are no more to worry about.

Comment: See if my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555753/transitive-closure) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given a relation $R$ defined on some set $A = \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, use the following algorithm to get the transitive closure:

```
For each k from 1 to n, do the following:
    For each i from 1 to n, do the following:
        For each j from 1 to n, do the following:
            If (a_i,a_k) and (a_k,a_j) are both in R, then do the following:
                Set R := R ∪ {(a_i,a_j)}.
```

This is a modified version of the Floyd–Warshall algorithm and has running time $O(n^3)$.

---

Note that if we run this algorithm on your given inputs, we would start by examining $a_1 = 0$. Since $(3,0) \in R$ and $(0,1),(0,2) \in R$, we would set $R:=R \cup \{(3,1),(3,2)\}$. This process repeats for each $a_k$.

Comment: I dont understand the order of the points. For example, why is it (1,2) instead of (2,1)?

Comment: Since $(1,3),(3,0),(0,2) \in R$, we know that $(1,2) \in R$. Imagine the numbers as vertices and draw an arrow from vertex $i$ to $j$ iff $(i,j) \in R$. Then it makes sense that $(1,2) \in R$ because the path $1 \to 3 \to 0 \to 2$ tells us that there is a path from $1$ to $2$. There is no way to get out of $2$ though; the only ordered pair in $R$ with $2$ as the first coordinate is the "loop" $(2,2)$.

Comment: so how do you know where to start?

Comment: Did you read my answer? I said: "...we would start by examining $a_1 = 0$. Since $(3,0) \in R$ and $(0,1),(0,2) \in R$, we would set $R:=R \cup \{(3,1),(3,2)\}$." Can you see how to do the next iteration?